# How to maintain the scroll position when switching from vertical to horizontal orientation in Flatlist?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

How can I maintain the scroll position when I switch from vertical to horizontal orientation in the flat list? A change of the `horizontal` prop resets the scroll position.

```
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        horizontal={isHorizontal} // change triggers reset to first item
      />
```

Comment: maybe if isHorizontal wasn't a state but a variable instead it wouldn't rerender the whole thing but not sure if that could work

Answer (score 0):

Flatlist has a method called scrollToIndex that is able to scroll to the specific item. You can leverage this to return to the correct scroll position by saving the index of the item that is in view in a useState and then passing the state to the scrollToIndex function whenever ishorizontal state is changed. I've created a basic example below.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, StatusBar, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const DATA = [
  {
    id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  {
    id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
    title: 'Second Item',
  },
  {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
    title: 'Third Item',
  },
  {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d73',
    title: 'forth Item',
  },
  {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d74',
    title: 'fifth Item',
  },
  {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d71',
    title: 'sixth Item',
  },
  {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29dfs',
    title: 'seven Item',
  },
  {
    id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29ddd',
    title: 'eight Item',
  },
];

const Item = ({ title }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
    <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

const App = () => {
  const [isHorizontal, setIsHorizontal] = useState(false)
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0)
  const flatListRef = useRef(null)
  const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item title={item.title} />
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscription = Dimensions.addEventListener(
      "change",
      ({ window: { width, height } }) => {
        if (width < height) {
          setIsHorizontal(true)
        } else {
          setIsHorizontal(false)
        }
      }
    );
    return () => subscription?.remove();
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if(flatListRef.current) {
      console.log(index);
      flatListRef.current?.scrollToIndex({index: index})
    }
  }, [isHorizontal]);

  const onViewRef = React.useRef((viewableItems) => {
    setIndex(viewableItems.viewableItems[1].index);
  });

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
      initialScrollIndex={index}
        ref={flatListRef}
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        onViewableItemsChanged={onViewRef.current}
        isHorizontal={isHorizontal}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: StatusBar.currentHeight || 0,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    padding: 20,
    margin:100
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: when do you you fire scollToIndex?